# How to get a value from properties table

Tags: java, sql

I have database table call properties and its stored web services link in it. I have created another record in the properties to get the value of A or B.

I need help on the query to get the value.

**Properties table**

```
Name               Value
------------------------------------
A                  http://A
B                  http://B
C                  Select * from properties where name = 'A' or name = 'B';
```

In records C I just get row A and B but I need to get the value in records A and B. If in my method input C it will check in both value A and B which is I already configured in C.

**expected output**

if method calling webservice C : its should checking on both webservices A and B

Comment: Question is not at all clear. What you want ?

Comment: in record C in my table i need to get the value of A and B so that when I calling that value C its can have both URL A and B

Comment: I think, I can understand what you mean.... If you call like 
`Select * from properties where name = 'C'` , do you want the values of A and B both should come ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: Show the code which does not what you want.

Comment: yes Surajit.. please help if you have any solution how to get both URL A or B in C

Comment: Ok, I will...tell me two things...
1. How do you want to get the data in C's Value (i.e. "http://A , http://B" or something else)
2. Which Database you are using ?

Comment: Surajit : the expected result value separated by comma (http://A , http://B) am using oracle database

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: You are already doing a lookup (select) on the table. If what you get back starts with `"http"`, you’re done. If not, you should do a new query on the database using the value you just got as your new SQL statement.